# Set java options for running playframework project in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I can run with overriden java options my playframework application using:
`run -Dprop1=val1 -Dprop2=val2` . It works perfectly.
But when I'm trying to do it via sbt build - props are not available.

So, I have scala file where my propject defined:

```
object PrjBuild extends Build  {
 val runSettings = Seq(
    fork in run := true,
    (javaOptions in run) ++= Seq(
      "-Dprop1=val1",
      "-Dprop2=val2")
  )

   lazy val root = Project(id = "my-play-project",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Seq(
      // some options here ...
      routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
    ) ++ runSettings
  ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
}
```

Please advice what am I doing wrong.
I was relying on `sbt fork` documentation:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html

But actually I would prefer to work without `fork`ing as `run -Dp1=v1` does not use `fork`ing. I want to perform same props setup but programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `run` without forking, you are using the same JVM as SBT.
If you want some props to be available in this JVM, you need to start SBT with them:

```
sbt -Dprop1=val1 -Dprop2=val2
```

Comment: I want this options affect only `run` task, but not any others.

Comment: You need to use something else then, like a config file.